# Print in foreach is giving error

Tags: php, loops, cakephp

View code is

```
foreach($post as $posts) 
{
   echo 'Title :'.$post['title'].'<br>';
   echo 'Body:'.$post['body'].'<br>';
}
```

error post is not found.......

if anybody find out any error, please help me

Comment: what is $post... it it $_POST or user defined variable/array ..? you are missing 's' inside the loop

Comment: What is $post? and paste actual error in the above question. the code is not supposed to give this error.

Comment: $posts is comming  from PostsController........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking like you are making mistake in foreach loop..

if data is coming from controller then according to convetion it may be $posts variable coming to post....
so interchange in foreach variable

try to do this...

```
  foreach($posts as $post)
```

i think it will work.............

Answer (score 1):

What is the context for your $posts variable?  I'm guessing you want to iterate through the array $posts, in which case your array expression and pointer value are mixed, try

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: print in foreach with comma you can use implode funciton

Answer (score 0):

At first look seems this will be fix,

```
foreach($post as $posts) 
{
   echo 'Title :'.$posts['title'].'<br>';
   echo 'Body:'.$posts['body'].'<br>';
}
```

But if $post is not defined then it will not give error, it will be warning actually.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong variable inside the loop, it should be:

```
foreach($post as $posts) {
   echo 'Title :'.$posts['title'].'<br>'; //you should use $posts not $post
   echo 'Body:'.$posts['body'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use implode function

' . implode(', ', $movies_to_display) . '';?>

' . implode('

', $movies_to_display) . '

';?>